# Exclude post_type or pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to exclude a specific post_type or pages, but I am not sure if I am thinking correctly. The issue is that all my pages comes up in my while query which is supposed to be dedicated for (almost) all my posts.

Here is what I am dealing with:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_taxonomy' => 'any',
    'cat' => -14,
);
```

I was thinking about writing `'post_type' => 'any'` into `posts`, but as I remember that didn't work with my custom posts.

Do anyone have a working solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about filtering post with `WP_Query` you should read something here https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Basically you can use a lot of filters, for example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat' => -14,
    'post__not_in' => array( 2, 5 )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This will find only posts (not pages), not in category with id 14 and not those with post ID 2 or 5.

Now if you could be more precise in your question I could give you the exact array you need to obtain it.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason  `'post_type' => 'post',` does not work with the custom posts. That's why I have chosen it to `any`. But thank you. Solved the problem using `'post__not_in' => array(8,6,21,10,12)`.

Comment: Just a small question @Michelem. How would it be if I want to exclude all the posts with the post_type `referanser`?

Comment: If you have registered your custom post type you can use it in the default filter `post_type` please refer to this http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types look at "Custom Post Types in the Main Query"